# Size WPF Grid Columns equally inside ListBox

Tags: wpf

Inside `ItemTemplate` I need two columns, each 50% width. Provided text is longer and is not wrapped, but occupy more width than expected.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="650">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListView">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus commodo dui vulput
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

To reproduce the sample you need call in code behind:

```cs
ListView.ItemsSource = new[] { new object() };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBlock receives all the width it wants in this setup, with the second grid column going off screen if need be. You can limit the width of the inner Grid to force it to distribute only the space it has:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus commodo dui vulput
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Works like a sharm! But the second column is not going off screen, I've tested with Borders and 3rd column at the end. And the middle was just smaller.

Comment: @JanZahradník, off-screening depends on the contents and their size. Copy of the same TextBlock in second column would force it off screen, for example. 
Glad it helped, sizing and arranging sometimes could be quite... fun =)